# Is it possible to count the number of divs after a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML structure is as follows

```
<div class="dateHeader">Yesterday</div>

<div class="trp" id="trp1"></div>

<div class="trp" id="trp2"></div>

<div class="trp" id="trp3"></div>

<div class="trp" id="trp4"></div>

<div class="dateHeader">9/1/2014</div>

<div class="trp" id="trp5"></div>

<div class="trp" id="trp6"></div>

<div class="trp" id="trp7"></div>
```

What I am hoping to do is detect div text that matches the word "Yesterday", then count all the divs that come after that div but before the next div of class 'dateHeader'.  So basicly count the # divs between two 'dateHeader' classes.

Is this possible?

I am also hoping to do some actions (like make CSS changes) to those divs that rest between the dateHeaders, but I assume once we can match those divs, i'd be able to easily manipulate them?

Comment: First Google result: http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/

Comment: Please explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:contains` and `.nextUntil()`

```
$('div.dateHeader:contains("Yesterday")').nextUntil('div.dateHeader').css('color','red')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2061Lm93/)**

To count, use:

```
$('div.dateHeader:contains("Yesterday")').each(function(){
    console.log ($(this).nextUntil('div.dateHeader').length)
})
```

Comment: The OP wanted to count the div.

Comment: @C-linkNepal - I was adding that as you typed.

Comment: $('div.dateHeader:contains("Yesterday")').nextUntil('div.dateHeader').length would be simple??

Comment: Impressive!  Works perfectly for what I needed, thanks so much!   +1

Answer (score 1):

You could filter through the elements, converting the text to lowercase. When a match is found, use `nextUntil`/`length` to get the number of succeeding elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1m13s47p/)

```
$('.dateHeader').filter(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('yesterday') > -1){
        console.log($(this).nextUntil('.dateHeader').length);
        // Logs 4
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `Jquery` next all method as http://api.jquery.com/nextall/